# Can we programatically search in Files for particular keywords

Tags: apex, files

If we go to Files tab in salesforce and there is  search functionality which searches within the files content and not just the name of the files and displays the result.

For eg. if we type in salesforce in the search box it will retrieve all files with word salesforce inside those files as well

[image]

Is there a way we can leverage this functionality programatically using apex?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can leverage this functionality of text content search in APEX. Only limitation is this would only work with TEXT files and not binary files like pdf,docs etc as binary files are encrypted.

But there is the catch, its not directly available. 
You will have to do couple of callouts to do this.

The file you upload has API name as "ContentDocument". It contains information as Name, fileType, description,extension and system fields.
There isn't a body tag to get content, thus we wont' get body content directly to our help. But we can get id of that file which can be used to fetch body later.

```
Select id ContentDocument where FileType='TEXT'
```

Now we have got  Id of file, next step is to find the download URL of the file.
Its present via **[connect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_files_content.htm)** namespace which can be acehived by making a callout.

Using the downloadURL you can get the file content by making an another callout, and search your specified string.

I have created a utility that searches file with their content,
As transactional limit applies, it can search max 50 files.
Hope that helps.

https://github.com/pranayjswl007/ApexFileSearcher